# In Windows 7 how do I change default open file dialog box to detail view?

Tags: windows-7

The open file dialog box defaults to the large icon view.

I would like to set the default on the "View Menu" to the details option. It is a real pain to
have to change that option every time I want to open a file

Any ideas?

**Note:**  This is not the explorer folder listing, but the open file dialog

Comment: Down-voted for accepting an answer that had nothing to do with the question! Move along, nothing to see here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Frankly I am not sure you can do that as each application has some control.
>   Check these and their Related Links :
>
> How to Set a Default Folder View for All Folders in Windows 7
>   http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/41198-folder-view-set-default-all-folders.html
>
> How to Change a Folder Template in Windows 7
>   http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3918-folder-template-change.html?filter
>
> How to Set a Default Folder Template for All Folders in Windows 7
>   http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/15699-folder-template-default.html
>
> How to Reset the Folder View Settings for All Folders with the Same Folder Template in Windows 7
>   http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11359-folder-view-reset-all-folders.html
>   Hope this helps.

[Source of Information](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/open-file-dialog-box-how-to-consistently-get-a/0775f6f1-5b4a-4d0d-be2e-63c30f84d2ee)

Software for XP, not sure if it works in W7 (doubtful), set a manual restore point before you decide install it in W7
http://www.file-ex.com/welcome.html

Comment: Thanks, but these are all the explorer folder listing, not the open file dialog

Comment: File-ex is not.

Comment: File-EX does not work with Windows 7

Comment: so there is no solution to this problem yet?

Comment: Just found this: "Set the desired view, then while holding down the CTRL key, click the Red "X" to close the dialog box. That view should become the default."  It's not red, but basically close the window with the control button down and it comes up the way you last set it next time. Brilliant!... if hidden feature.

Comment: @Stu, could you please turn your comment into an answer?